Is it okay to use qiskit.primitives BackendSampler with qiskit_ibm_runtime real hardware?
I would like to run QAOA from the qiskit_algorithm on real quantum hardware. Currently, the SamplerV2 provided by qiskit_ibm_runtime is not compatible with qiskit_algorithms, so I looked for alternative Samplers. I found the BackendSampler in qiskit.primitives and wrote the following code accordingly. While the code executes, I am unsure if it is actually running on the real quantum hardware as I intended.
Is it okay to use the backend from qiskit_ibm_runtime with BackendSampler?
My code:
from qiskit.primitives import BackendSampler

service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel="ibm_quantum")

backend=service.least_busy()

sampler=BackendSampler(backend=backend)

meo=MinimumEigenOptimizer(min_eigen_solver=QAOA(reps=2,sampler=sampler, optimizer=COBYLA()))

result = meo.solve(qubo)

